# FLURL: mapping property names

Tags: c#, flurl

Is there any way to map non-matching property names when doing `ReceiveJson()`? For example 'user_name' in JSON should map to 'UserName' in C# object.

```
List<Person> people = await _settings.Url
    .AppendPathSegment("people")
    .GetAsync()
    .ReceiveJson<List<Person>>();
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### *Updated answer for Flurl.Http 4.0 and beyond:*

Starting with 4.0 (in prerelease as of June 2022), Flurl.Http uses System.Text.Json for serialization, so [any of its prescribed methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-customize-properties) for customizing property names will work with Flurl:

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

public class Person
{
    [JsonPropertyName("user_name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

A Json.NET serializer is [available](https://gist.github.com/tmenier/158ede5f33703036a0c26080adf2b8b9) for 4.0 and beyond for those who prefer it, in which case use the approach below.

### *For Flurl.Http 3.x and earlier:*

Prior to 4.0, Flurl.Http used Newtonsoft Json.NET, so using that library's serialization attributes, specifically [JsonProperty](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm), will work in those versions:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Person
{
    [JsonProperty("user_name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Todd, this does not work for me. I'm using `PostUrlEncodedAsync` and `ReceiveJson<MyClass>`. When I use the `[JsonProperty("user_name")]`, the property is not filled. However if I name the property `user_name` is it filled.

Comment: @c.lamont.dev I've updated this answer

Comment: Is it possible to customize property names when using PostUrlEncodedAsync()?
(I already tried DataContract / DataMember - Attributes without success)

Comment: @Sascha There's nothing like this. DataContract is from the XML world, and since URL-encoded is not XML (nor is it JSON), these attributes don't work.